# mDNS support with cloud DNS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns

#### Problem: .local cannot resolve across multiple clouds.

Due to reasons I don't understand .local is used in one of our hybrid cloud environments. When trying to test out DNS resolution in gcloud I'm continually getting SERVFAIL while trying to resolve any of those records.

#### Attempted solutions:

cloud dns managed zones(both private manually managed and private forwarded to zone).

1. company.local [forwarded zone] -> SERVFAIL
2. company.local [non-forwarded managed private] -> SERVFAIL
3. randomname.local [non-forwarded managed private] -> SERVFAIL
4. companyfake.com [non-forwarded managed private] -> SUCCESS
5. comany.com [non-forwarded managed private] -> SUCCESS

#### Possible reason

I'm pretty sure that RFC 6762 explains why this cross cloud .local request doesn't make any sense.

```sh
This document specifies that the DNS top-level domain ".local." is a
   special domain with special semantics, namely that any fully
   qualified name ending in ".local." is link-local, and names within
   this domain are meaningful only on the link where they originate.
```

#### Other diagnostic tidbits

cloudA:

- tcpdump shows connects on port 53
- tcpdump shows no connections on port 5353 during nslookup

gcloud:

- tcpdump shows no connections on 53 during nslookup
- tcpdump shows no connections on 5353 during nslookup

interactive nslookup works when specifying the server ip.

#### Summary

I'm fairly certain I'm trying to do something I shouldn't be able to within cloud DNS, but I don't have any specifics. I'm trying to avoid introducing new processes:

1. pre-pending DHCP resolution
2. converting DNS records `company.local` from one cloud to `gcp.company.com` in another

But I'd like to see some thoughts/ suggestions on what I am missing here.

Comment: Please provide more information: **1**. configurations of DNS zones in cloudA and gcloud. **2**. configuration of interconnect between clouds . **3**. locations in network your test points to check DNS.

Comment: 1) Google Cloud VPCs do not support multicast therefore mDNS will not function. 2) You should stop using `.local` domain names. 3) Read this article for a better understand of `.local` gTLD. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local